# Is it possible to track and report working effort with Team Foundation Server?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm not sure, if stackoverflow is the right place to ask this. Anyway, we are using Team Foundation Server at our company and I was asked if there is a way to track and report working effort per project or per some other development unit.
I know there is task management with tickets and with the agile process template, one can assing some measurable unit of working effort to a ticket. But is there also a reporting facility? I didn't find anything so far. Maybe there are such features, but our subscription doesn't include them. If so, is there any website that lists the supported features for each subscription. I didn't find anything about that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can create reports about every measure assiciated with, e.g. work items. Additionally you can add arbitrary fields to working items, e.g. the program unit/module the working item belongs to. You can then create a report that sums the actual effort per program unit.